# Is this a valid proof for a limit approaching infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Proof that $\displaystyle \lim_{i \to \infty} \bigg | \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\bigg |=0 $

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and let 
$$N=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } 1 \geq \epsilon\\
\epsilon & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

*Note:* whether or not $1 \geq \epsilon$, it follows that $N \geq 1$ and $N \geq \epsilon$.

Assume $i>N$

Since $i>N\geq 1$, $\sqrt{i}>\sqrt{N}\geq \sqrt{1}$.

We then have 
$\bigg |\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\bigg |=\frac{1}{|\sqrt{i}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}<1 \leq N$

My main worry about this proof is near $\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}<1$. My justification here is that $i>N \geq 1$ and for any number $t>1$ we get $\sqrt{t}>\sqrt{1}=1$. Furthermore, for numbers $a$ and $b$, if $a>b>0$ then $\frac{b}{a} < 1$. Thus $\sqrt{i}>1>0$ so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} <1$.

Comment: When calculating a limit, note that if $N$ fits to some $\varepsilon$ then it necessarily fits any $\varepsilon'>\varepsilon$.

Comment: You seem to prove that $\bigg |\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\bigg |\leq N$, but you need to prove it $\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: can we not just choose N = int(1/E^2) + 1 or something simple and show it in one line?

Comment: Yes we can. $ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are confused about the definition of a limit.  Suppose we have a sequence $\{u_n\}$, and want to prove that $u_n \rightarrow L$.  You need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a number $N$ such that for all natural numbers $n > N$
$$
|u_n-L| < \epsilon.
$$
The number $L$ is called the *limit*.

In this question, that is the same as showing
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon.
$$

To prove this, suppose $\epsilon>0$ and then let $n > N = \epsilon^{-2}$.  (Note that you can't use $N$ as an index, it is not in general a natural number.  This may differ with local usages.) Then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^{-2}}}
 = \epsilon,
$$
as required.